# Delphi 2010 - patch/redirect RTL record method

Tags: delphi, runtime, delphi-2010

Is it possible to patch/redirect any method of a record defined in RTL? If it is, how to do it?

I'm trying to patch `TValue.TryCast` function, i want to redirect this function to my function definition from where i jump to orinal function and after that i check for additional stuff and exit.

To put some light on this topic, here is what i'm doing now and it did not work.
I declare:

```pascal
type
  TValueHelper = record helper for TValue
  public
    function TryCastFixed(ATypeInfo: PTypeInfo; out AResult: TValue): Boolean;
  end;

var
  TValueTryCastOrgAddr: Pointer;

function TValueHelper.TryCastFixed(ATypeInfo: PTypeInfo; out AResult: TValue): Boolean;
begin
  asm
    JMP TValueTryCastOrgAddr
  end;
  // fix for conversion from TValue
  if not Result and (ATypeInfo <> Nil) and (ATypeInfo = System.TypeInfo(TValue)) then begin
    AResult := TValue.From<TValue>(Self);
    Exit(True);
  end;
end;
```

and then there is a patching stuff:

```pascal
type
  PAbsoluteIndirectJmp = ^TAbsoluteIndirectJmp;
  TAbsoluteIndirectJmp = packed record
    OpCode: Word;   //$FF25(Jmp, FF /4)
    Addr: ^Pointer;
  end;

function WriteProtectedMemory(BaseAddress, Buffer: Pointer; Size: Cardinal; out WrittenBytes: Cardinal): Boolean;
var
  OldProtect, Dummy: Cardinal;
begin
  WrittenBytes := 0;
  if Size > 0 then begin // VirtualProtect for DEP issues
    OldProtect := 0;
    Result := VirtualProtect(BaseAddress, Size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, OldProtect);
    if Result then try
      Move(Buffer^, BaseAddress^, Size);
      WrittenBytes := Size;
      if OldProtect in [PAGE_EXECUTE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READ, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY] then
        FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess, BaseAddress, Size);
    finally
      Dummy := 0;
      VirtualProtect(BaseAddress, Size, OldProtect, Dummy);
    end;
  end;
  Result := WrittenBytes = Size;
end;

function GetActualAddr(Proc: Pointer): Pointer;
begin
  if Proc <> Nil then begin
    if (PAbsoluteIndirectJmp(Proc).OpCode = $25FF) then
      Result := PAbsoluteIndirectJmp(Proc).Addr^
    else
      Result := Proc;
  end
  else
    Result := Nil;
end;

procedure RedirectFunction(OldP, DestP: Pointer);
type
  TJump = packed record
    Jmp: Byte; // $E9;
    Offset: Integer;
  end;

var
  Jump: TJump;
  WrittenBytes: Cardinal;
begin
  if IsLibrary then
    raise Exception.Create('RedirectFunction: Not allowed in a DLL');
  //
  OldP := GetActualAddr(OldP); 
  TValueTryCastOrgAddr := OldP;
  DestP := GetActualAddr(DestP);
  Jump.Jmp := $E9;
  Jump.Offset := Integer(DestP) - Integer(OldP) - SizeOf(TJump);
  WriteProtectedMemory(OldP, @Jump, SizeOf(TJump), WrittenBytes);
end;

procedure PatchTValueHelper_TryCast;
begin
  RedirectFunction(@@TValue.TryCast, @@TValueHelper.TryCastFixed); // this is not working, 
  // as it can't access undeclared record, how to do it correctly?
end;
```

As can be seen, code is completed from bits and pieces from internet, and `PatchTValueHelper_TryCast` is my main problem.
How to patch function from this record globally?

Thanks, NevTon.

Comment: What does this have to do with the VCL?

Maybe I'm not completely following how you're trying to achieve this, but I don't think this is possible.  Virtual and dynamic methods of a Class or Object have their address in a lookup table, but if I'm right, static methods like this have no such lookup table, and the compiler simply inserts the method address in the code in every place you call the method.

Comment: Sorry, i was thinking about RTL, but at 3 am, after more than 16 hours of work, my brain was somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try https://github.com/MahdiSafsafi/DDetours? This is a library specifically designed for hooking Delphi functions. Disclaimer: I do know know if it can intercept record helper methods.

Comment: Yes i did, it seems that there is no solution for me. May be i want to do something that is not possible or i do not understand delphi enough.

Comment: Second try - deeper look - there may be something in it, but I have partial success, but trampoline works only to the point where entering original function does AV.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the code to patch would be this:

```
RedirectFunction(@TValue.TryCast, @TValue.TryCastFixed);
```

But your `TryCastFixed` implementation is broken and will lead to a stack overflow or worse. Redirecting the way you did simple scribbles a jmp instruction into the first 5 bytes of the executable code of `TryCast`. This means whenever you call or jump to the original method it will jump to your method. If your method jumps back you have an endless loop of jumping back and forth. Your jmp instruction also happens after some code that was already executed within the begin of your method that the compiler created. This means values in registers are possibly not the same anymore and you cannot simple use the jmp instruction here.

If you want to still use the original method then you need to use libraries such as DDetours or madCodeHook (I assume there are others).

Otherwise I suggest you simply copy the code from the RTL TryCast into your routine and add the fix so you can get away with the redirect as you don't need the original method anymore then.

Comment: Right, this is what i did not seen for myself. And more, it seems that this redirect works once and second call to `TryCast` made by RTL ends up in oryginal method not in mine. Which functionality/method call of DDetours could help me with what i need to achive?